# Jquery drag, drop and clone proper positioning

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

## **UPDATED**

Fiddle Here:

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/przbadu/rkvdffe3/4/)

[full-screen-result](http://jsfiddle.net/przbadu/rkvdffe3/4/embedded/result/)

NOTE: I am new to fiddle, and somehow I integrated my code to fiddle, but drag drop is not working on it.

Hi I have implemented drag, drop and clone feature with the help of jquery draggable and droppable functions which looks like this:

```
$(".dragSigners").draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  cursor: 'move',
  tolerance: 'fit',
  revert: true 
});
```

**NOTE: `$("#document-reader")` is an scrollable div. I want to drag element anywhere in this div from top to bottom. I can scroll parent div and drag element in the middle of the div. And it should stick where I dragged it.**

```
$("#document-reader").droppable({
  accept: '.dragSigners',
  activeClass: "drop-area",

  drop: function(e, ui) {
    dragEl = ui.helper.clone();
    ui.helper.remove();

    document_id   = dragEl.data("document-id");
    signer_id     = dragEl.data("signer-id");
    stopPosition  = dragEl.position();
    dragEl.data("signer-id", signer_id);

    dragEl.draggable({
      helper: 'original',
      cursor: 'move',
      tolerance: 'fit',
      drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).remove();
      }
    });

    // append element to #document-reader
    dragEl.addClass("dragMe");
    dragEl.removeClass("dragSigners col-sm-6");
    dragEl.find("span.closeIt").removeClass("hideIt");
    dragEl.appendTo('#document-reader');

    // ajax call for updating position to database for future reference
    updateDropPosition(dragEl, stopPosition, signer_id, document_id)
  }
});
```

This is properly dragging an element, clonning it and dropping it.

**PROBLEM**

The dropped element is not dropping in exactly same place where I dropped it. Rather it is dropping in same place every time I drop element. I tried to log the positions also, and found that **top** and **left** are same, whereever I dropped the element.

```
console.log(dragEl.position())

output:  Object { top=-5, left=-5} // [NOTE: it doesn't matter where ever I drop element, It is showing top and left as -5. and it is not showing dropped element in the exact same place where I dropped it]
```

Don't know what is the problem with my code.

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

Please visite these screenshots:

1) This is happening right now (wrong behavior)
[image: current behavior]

2) Expected behavior:
[image: expected behavior]

Comment: prepare jsfiddle if possible

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try to do that. I am new to js fiddle. I will give it a try

Comment: I added jsfiddle and shared link above, thanks

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work since you didn't include jqueryui. Use this bootply instead http://www.bootply.com/tFeAV4mNlU -- it includes the bootstrap and jqueryUI

Comment: HI Skelly, I have added jqueryUI in my jsfiddle. That is what happening in my real web app. But it is not the expected result. I want to display dropped element in the exact position where I dropped it. I have mentioned it in ```expected result``` section above in question just above attached images. Please see attached screenshot also for expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `dragMe` and `parent` class in parent draggable element.

Now, use `dragSigners` class for dragging and cloning element. And use `dragMe` for dragging newly cloned element. Also set `dragMe` `position: relative`.

Here, is a complete

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/przbadu/rkvdffe3/11/)

full screen output: [jsfiddle full screen output](http://jsfiddle.net/przbadu/rkvdffe3/11/embedded/result/)

**[NOTE: I have opened new problem, please follow link for that problem: [jquery drag, drop and clone, find dropped position of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938520/jquery-drag-drop-and-clone-find-dropped-position-of-element])**