# jquery drag, drop and clone, find dropped position of element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Here, is my fiddle for jquery drag, drop and clone feature.

**Problem:**

My problem is: when ever I drop element, it is showing:

```
position: {top: 0, left: 0}
```

only for draggable, clone and droppable element.

I have also written code for finding position using only `draggable` function and that is working fine. I want this behavior in `draggable, droppable with clone feature`

**Please visit JSFiddle**

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/przbadu/rkvdffe3/16/)

[full-screen output](http://jsfiddle.net/przbadu/rkvdffe3/16/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, resolved the problem. The problem was, I was using `ui.draggable.position();` for storing dropped position to database, which was wrong.

The actual position we need to store is:

```
// position of the draggable minus position of the droppable
// relative to the document
leftPosition  = ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left;
topPosition   = ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top;
```

Reference: [How do I get the coordinate position after using jQuery drag and drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849030/how-do-i-get-the-coordinate-position-after-using-jquery-drag-and-drop)

Updated Jsfiddle with working example

http://jsfiddle.net/przbadu/rkvdffe3/18/

http://jsfiddle.net/przbadu/rkvdffe3/18/embedded/result/

Comment: Old post here, but thought I would ask anyways. I noticed that when you drop an element onto the page it loads 2 coordinates. So after you move it again, it loads a more accurate coordinates. Do you have any more updated code on this? This is very similar to what I'm looking to accomplish, but not with signatures. Thanks!

Comment: @Justin Yes, it's too old post. Unfortunately I don't have updated code.

Comment: Are you using it anywhere? or know of another solution similar to this?

Comment: I was using this for my old project but i don't have access to that private repository now :)

Comment: No problem, just thought id ask. This might have gotten me to the next step anyways.  Thanks!