# How do I do Drag and Drop in js/html from one column to an area keeping object in column available to re drag

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to build a small app.
one column has 5 rectangles. (vertically aligned)
I want to drag&drop the rectangle into another area, while keeping the same rectangle in the column, so I could drag&drop it again.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible, you will just need to clone the rectangle. Something similar to this... http://jsfiddle.net/przbadu/rkvdffe3/18/ Got this from this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938520/jquery-drag-drop-and-clone-find-dropped-position-of-element

Comment: I have my d&d working. I am trying to have a dblclick event on the dropped  object, but keep getting a jquery error.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Yea depending on what jquery library you are using, you need to bind the newly created div to the Live() or On() event. i updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/96e7xk3b/1/

Comment: Thanks
I used the code you supplied in jFiddle.
I can't seem to find the dropped object in order to do the dbl click event on it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to send a code example of what you have so for? maybe create a fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74285/discussion-between-jacques-and-motti10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Check the link http://jsfiddle.net/tt99ugsf/

```
$('.square1').draggable({
    revert:"valid",
    helper:"clone"
});
```

The trick is to clone the div